# what is meant by 'install function' in the vue.js documentation?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to create a vue component library so I began doing some research and I stumbled upon this [guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/packaging-sfc-for-npm.html) from the official vue.js documentation. In this [part](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/packaging-sfc-for-npm.html#What-does-my-packaged-component-look-like) of the guide, it talks about creating an install function. I was wondering if you could help me understand what exactly an install function is and what it does? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `install` function is there for `Vue.use`. Whenever you call `Vue.use` the install function will be called.

Whenever you call `Vue.use` it will call `Plugin.install(Vue)`. It is there to let the user of your library can use your component library by installing it.

And I think the logic in the `install` function is quite obvious. It prevents multiple installs of this plugin and it will create a component.